# About IntelliJ idea, running applet reported an error: the main class could not be found or loaded

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

package java_obj;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**

- @Author CCUT_chao
- @Software IntelliJ IDEA
- @Time 2021/8/31
  */

public class MyFirstApplet extends Applet {
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.drawString("Hello Applet", 20, 20);
}
}

Comment: Applets are a very old technology that is not supported anymore in current versions of Java. If you're following a tutorial that teaches you how to write applets, then find a better, newer tutorial and forget about applets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.